# is it possible to find the flutter ios build ipa file when using xcode 14.1

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using xcode 14.1 to build the flutter app, but I could not found the ipa files from the folder. where should I found the ipa file? I have tried to find the ios ipa file from the path:

```
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-adtpuxbuupwwgxamxwiaqkpdrece/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

there is no ipa files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your terminal while on your project path write:

```
flutter build ipa
```

After the build you can find the ipa file in this path:

```
/YourProject/build/iOS/ipa
```